# Overwrite arguments within a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have a function that allows a lot of arguments, and to make things easier I decided to include another variable where arguments are introduced as a list (named `args` in the example below).

```
foo <- function(x, a, b, c, args, ...) {

ifelse(missing(a)==TRUE, a<-1, NA)
ifelse(missing(b)==TRUE, b<-2, NA)
ifelse(missing(c)==TRUE, c<-3, NA)

if(missing(args)==FALSE) {
for(i in 1:length(args)) {
    tmp <- as.vector(args[[i]])
    assign(names(args)[i], get("tmp"))
}
}

# Need something that overwrites "args" when the 
# other arguments are specified

print(list(x=x, a=a, b=b, c=c))

}
```

And the function `foo` gives the following:

```
foo(0)
$x
[1] 0

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

Here `my_args` records the profile arguments.

```
my_args <- list(a=1, b=1, c=1)
```

to produce:

```
foo(0, args=my_args)
$x
[1] 0

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 1

$c
[1] 1
```

I would like to find a way to overwrite values in `args` whenever the corresponding arguments are specified in the function. Although the user specified two different values for the same argument, there are circumstances in which this makes sense.

For instance,

```
foo(0, args=my_args, c=3)
$x
[1] 0

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 1

$c
[1] 3
```

And this is to see what happens when `c=3` within the profile recorded in `my_args`.

I appreciate very much some help.

Comment: a simple thought was having an additional if() check if both(a/b/c or args) are non-missing and then setting as per you choice.

Comment: @joel.wilson I have tried several conditionals including `if(!(exists(names(args)[i])))` and `if(missing(substitute(names(args)[i])))` without success, but I'll see with the option both(a/b/c or args). Thanks

Comment: I'd define `function(x, a = NA, b = NA, c = NA, args = list(a = a, b = b, c = c), ...)` and only use `args` in the function.

Comment: Thanks. There are however other potential arguments `d`, `e`, etc. that need to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows arguments to be passed via the `args` list or via `...` in which case they overwrite those in `args`.  If an argument is passed in neither then it takes on the default value. The `stopifnot` statement raises an error if arguments other than those listed in `defaults` are passed in `...` or in `args`. It can be used to prevent additional arguments, not listed in `defaults`, from being passed.  Alternately, that line can be omitted altogether to allow unlimited arguments.

```
foo <- function(x, ..., args = list()) {   
  defaults <- list(a = -1, b = -2, c = -3, d = -4)  
  Args <- Reduce(modifyList, list(defaults, args, list(...)))
  stopifnot(all(names(Args) %in% names(defaults)))
  Args
}

foo(0, a = 1, b = 2, args = list(a = 10, c = 20))
```

giving:

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 20

$d
[1] -4
```

Comment: This is an excellent option! Thanks. Actually by opening `defaults <- list(a = -1, b = -2, c = -3, d = -4, ...)` it is possible to include unlimited arguments like `foo(0, a = 1, b = 2, d=5, args = list(a = 10, c = 20), e = 9, z = "char")`, and that is what I was looking for.

Comment: That could give rise to two different components with the same name in `defaults`. Instead, if you want unlimited arguments then just omit `stopifnot(...)`. I have now clarified this in the answer.

Comment: That is correct. Just by opening the `defaults` this list _and_ the entered arguments are printed. Now your function works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of this structure, in the sense that the assignment of default values for `a` `b` and `c` is very unclear from looking at the code. But this is one way of doing what you want:

```
foo <- function(x, a = NA, b = NA, c = NA, args = NULL, ...) {
  if (is.null(args)) {
    a <- ifelse(is.na(a), 1, a)
    b <- ifelse(is.na(b), 2, b)
    c <- ifelse(is.na(c), 3, c)
  } else {
    args[!is.na(c(a, b, c))] <- c(a, b, c)[!is.na(c(a, b, c))]
    lapply(names(args), function(x) assign(x, args[[x]], inherits = TRUE))
  }
  print(list(x=x, a=a, b=b, c=c))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Axeman for the answer. However, `c(a, b, c)` is just an example, and I need to evaluate combinations of (other) potential arguments in the function, and control flow seems to be needed. Nonetheless, your code works, and I am going to look at this option further.